# Android: Reusing an activity stored as local variable in another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, reusability

I have two activities in my Android 2.1 application.

The first is the Main activity, with a view offering touch interaction.

The second is the Settings activity, offering settings to adjust parameters which are used within Main.

I currently have a Settings activity within my Main class, as a class instance. I read settings from this instance within Main.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {
    protected Settings settings;
}

public class Settings extends Activity implements ListAdapter {
}
```

I've discovered how to reuse my Settings activity if it has already been created, ensuring only one persistent instance:

```
// within Main.java :
Intent intent = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); // reuse existing Settings
this.startActivity(intent);
```

My issue is that I cannot discover how to tie this in with the local 'settings' member in Main.

Would someone be kind enough to give me a quick example of how I can start my local 'settings' instance as a reusable activity?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I currently have a Settings activity within my Main class, as a class instance.

Delete this **immediately**. One activity should not be holding onto another activity, as this results in memory leaks. I guarantee you that there are better solutions for whatever problem you think that you are solving this way.

> My issue is that I cannot discover how to tie this in with the local 'settings' member in Main.

By deleting "the local 'settings' member in Main", this problem goes away.

Also, please use `SharedPreferences` and a `PreferenceActivity` for collecting "settings" wherever possible. For example, if the point behind "the local 'settings' member in Main" is to allow `Main` to access the settings, the right answer for that is for the settings to be stored in a `SharedPreferences` object and for `Main` to be using those `SharedPreferences`. Using a `PreferenceActivity` has the benefit of giving the user a look and feel that they expect when providing settings to an application.

Comment: Many thanks for this clear advice. I'm new to Android, and have much to learn. I'm consulting your code here for a working example: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/src/com/commonsware/android/prefdialogs

Comment: @KomodoDave: That's not a bad example, though the actual preference XML is kinda goofy -- it's for demonstrating techniques, more so than being a model of great preference design. :-)

Comment: Point taken - for anyone interested, there's a more comprehensive example here, showing all the code/xml required: http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences